# make siunitx the decimal points alignment starts from the 3rd row of the table

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, formatting, siunitx, punctuation

I got a table has two rows as titles at the top of it, and numbers in the rest cells, so I've checked the document of the siunitx, It says something abt multicolumn but its kinda different from  what I want. Here is my latex code.

```
\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\multirow{2}{*}{twoc} & head   \\
                      & sub    \\
one                   & 3.456  \\
two                   & \textbf{23.657}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

so basically its abt the `multirow` command I used here, and seems `siunitx` by default affects from the 2nd row if you put `S[table-format=3.2]` in the tabular, since I want it affects from the 3rd row cause I've got first 2 rows as titles, what should I do. Any good suggestions?

Comment: Your code isn't compilable. Please read about [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that), adjust your question and it'll be easier for people to test your code and suggest corrections. Thank you.

Comment: @Miyase thanks, and I've changed my table codes, I merely want to align the 2 numbers with the decimal point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

As you see, numbers in third row are aligned at decimal pints, in the fourth row is centered.

Last (second) column is of `S` type, defined in the `siunitx` package:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm, varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newrobustcmd\B{\DeclareFontSeriesDefault[rm]{bf}{b}%
                \bfseries}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\sisetup{detect-weight,
         mode=text,
         table-format = 2.3}
\begin{tabular}{l S}
    \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{two}    & {head}    \\
                        & {sub}     \\
    \hline
one                     &    3.456  \\
two                     &\B 23.657  \\
three                   & {12345}   \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

is this what you looking for?

Comment: That's awesome! It works and I remain a few questions. Seems `{}` can maintain its original format, that's what I was looking for, or the `sub` may display improperly. And why `\textbf` doesn't work, what's the difference between them.

Comment: @CupY, curly braces protect contents from align mechanism at decimal points. default is centered, but you can define other positioning (left, right). For details see package documentation. `\t` works inside braces, but then then formatting at decimal point is lost. For boldface numbers you need to switch cell to "boldface mode" (by use defined `\B`) and tell to siunitx (before) that should be aware of text weight.